# On mobile screens, my divs are showing an unwanted white border

Tags: html, css

My problem is that when you view my website on a mobile screen or in the chrome developer mobile tools, the two **divs** at the top of my page are creating a very thin white border. This cannot be seen in a regular browser view.

I was previously having that issue for the divs where I used the Lorem Ipsum title and description but that was when I had set the body to have a background color. I did some poking around and saw people had said that adding a background color to the body causes that issue. When I removed the **background color** from the body, the white outlines disappeared from those divs, and now started showing in my nav.

I have tried setting **margins, padding, and borders** to 0, as well as **outline:none** but none of those solved my issues.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}

.left_logo_nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  height: 86px;
  background-color: #0D6AE8;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0D6AE8;
  height: 86px;
  width: 50%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 975px;
  background-color: #0D6AE8;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="left_logo_nav">
      <a href="index.html"><img class="top_logo" src="svg/franco_logo.svg" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="main-nav">
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="#">Climate</a></li>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>

  </div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making Box div as outer div and giving background-color for this class will remove white line

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}

.left_logo_nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  height: 86px;
  
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  
  height: 86px;
  width: 50%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #0D6AE8;
}

.gap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 975px;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="left_logo_nav">
      <a href="index.html"><img class="top_logo" src="svg/franco_logo.svg" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="main-nav">
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="#">Climate</a></li>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
  <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried editing my code to what you suggested but I still get the same issue when it's viewed on a mobile screen

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly find an answer to what was causing those thin lines around my divs in mobile view but changing the sizing to different units did create somewhat of a difference.

I did a simple work-around to where instead of coloring each individual div, I made a container for the 3 divs and added the background color to that instead.

```
       <div class="section_1">

         <div class="box">

           <div class="left_logo_nav"><a href="index.html"><img class="top_logo" 
           src="svg/franco_logo.svg" alt="Logo"/></a></div>

            <nav class="main-nav">
              <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" 
              href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" href="#">Climate</a></li>
              <li class="no-bullet"><a class="nav-text" 
              href="contact.html">Contact</a> 
              </li>
            </nav>

          </div>

          <div class="gap"></div>

        </div>
```

And for the CSS I removed the background-colors and added it to .section_1

```
            .section_1 {
                background_color: #0D6AE8;
            }
```